# Logging for a flask app

Tags: python, multithreading, logging, flask

I am developing a webapp with flask that acts as interface to a python library that makes computations (usually time consuming).

Each call to the server is identified with an identifier, and I want to write logs of calls to the library to a file that depends on the given identifier.

A minimal working example is as follows.

### computations.py

```
import time
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def long_computation(identifier):
    logger.info('called computation with identifier %s', identifier)
    for i in range(100):
        logger.info('in step %d of identifier %s', i, identifier)
        time.sleep(1)
    logger.info('finished computation with identifier %s')
```

### server.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
import logging
import threading
import computations

app = Flask(__name__)

def call_computation(identifier):
    fh = logging.FileHandler("computations-%s.log" % identifier)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(name)s : %(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    computations.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    computations.logger.addHandler(fh)
    computations.long_computation(identifier)
    computations.logger.removeHandler(fh)

@app.route('/node/<identifier>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def serve_node(identifier):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=call_computation, args=(identifier,))
    thread.start()
    return "I will compute it!"
```

When I make a call to the server, say `http://127.0.0.1:5000/node/A` it creates the logfile `computations-A.log` and logs correctly to this file. However if I make another call to the server, say `http://127.0.0.1:5000/node/B` before the first computation ends, then it creates the log file `computations-B.log`, but the logs of both computations, corresponding to the different calls to `call_computation` go to both files. That is, both files `computations-A.log` and `computations-B.log` have, for instance, lines like:

```
2018-08-02 20:31:57,524 INFO     computations : in step 56 of identifier B
2018-08-02 20:31:57,799 INFO     computations : in step 97 of identifier A
```

Could anyone please help me in order to make the calls to the library to go to the appropiate log file? Notice that I cannot, in principle, modify the package that makes the computations, so that I cannot create more loggers inside that package.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to filter the log records. In the `server.py` file create a subclass of `logging.Filter`:

```
class MyFilter(logging.Filter):
    def __init__(self, thread_id):
        super(MyFilter, self).__init__()
        self.thread_id = thread_id

    def filter(self, record):
        return record.thread == self.thread_id
```

and when setting up the handler, add an instance of this class:

```
myfilter = MyFilter(threading.current_thread().ident)
fh.addFilter(myfilter)
```

This way, when a log record reaches the filter, if the thread that created the log is the same that created the filter, then it will pass to the next level; otherwise it will get filtered out.